# Python Basic if statements

Tags: python

Hi Guys for the below code i want to execute only if the first condition satisfy so please help me

```
print('welcome')
username = input()
if(username == "kevin"):
 print("Welcome"+username)
else:
 print("bye")
password = input()
if(password == "asdfg"):
 print("Acess Granted")
else:
 print("You Are not Kevin")
```

Comment: Can you explain more what you are trying to do ?

Comment: I think you want to put the part from `password = input()` under the first if condition....just put everything under the condition you want to happen when that condition is met....you haven't asked a reasonable question.

Comment: i just to display the If the first condition true then the code have to continue it if is false it should execute the second code am i a clear ?

Comment: please help here bro

Comment: please help here bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got this right, you want to exit/terminate the script at the "else" block of the 1st if statement.

There are two approaches - 1st is that you use sys.exit():

```
import sys
#if statement here
...
else:
    print("bye")
    sys.exit()
```

2nd is that you put your 2nd if under the 1st if's else block:

```
...
else:
    password = input()
    if password=="abcdef":
        #do something here
    else:
        print("you're not Kevin")
```

Also, I see that you're using brackets after the if statements (`if (condition):`). That is not necessary for Python 3.x as far as I'm concerned.

See: https://repl.it/CEl7/0

Comment: Thanks bro i will try it

Comment: Sorry it is nor working when i use the first type even if i enter kevin the code ends , please help bro .

Comment: What is your Python version?

Comment: i am using Python 3.x  bro

Comment: Make sure that you only write sys.exit() when you really want to exit. Not at the first part of the if statement. Also, try using the 2nd version. It's safer AND its a better practice :)

Comment: import sys
print('welcome')
username = input()
if(username == "kevin"):
 print("Welcome"+username)
else:
 print("bye")
sys.exit()
password = input()
if(password == "asdfg"):
 print("Acess Granted")
else:
 print("You Are not Kevin")

Comment: i want to execute the second code if the first condition true please help

Comment: Thanks bro, can u provide me any link that i can learn python